# How do i collect multiple list from a List<TradeChartDTO> by using java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have list of TradeChartDTOs and i want to collect multiple list form this list.
And I did like this. 
But i want to collect by using single stream. I do not want stream again and again for collecting multiple list.

**I did this.**

```java
private Map<String, Object> getJsonAccordingToChartApi(List<TradeChartDTO> tradeChartDTO) {
        List<BigDecimal> high = tradeChartDTO.stream().map(chart -> chart.getHigh()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<BigDecimal> low = tradeChartDTO.stream().map(chart -> chart.getLow()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<BigDecimal> close = tradeChartDTO.stream().map(chart -> new BigDecimal(chart.getClose())).collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<BigDecimal> open = tradeChartDTO.stream().map(chart -> new BigDecimal(chart.getOpen())).collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<BigDecimal> volume = tradeChartDTO.stream().map(chart -> chart.getVolume()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<BigDecimal> timestamp = tradeChartDTO.stream().map(chart -> new BigDecimal(chart.getTimestamp())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Map<String, Object> mainData = new HashMap<>();
        mainData.put("t", timestamp);
        mainData.put("c", close);
        mainData.put("o", open);
        mainData.put("v", volume);
        mainData.put("h", high);
        mainData.put("l", low);
        return mainData;
    }
```

**TradeChartDTO.java**

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TradeChartDTO {

    private Integer timestamp;

    private BigDecimal volume;

    private String open;

    private BigDecimal high;

    private BigDecimal low;

    private String close;

    private BigDecimal price;
}
```

Is there any other way do this?

Comment: Clean and simple code. You really want to make it worse?

Comment: try asking on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I am aware to do is to introduce a map of the very same keys and mapping functions to help you transform the DTO:

```
Map<String, Function<TradeChartDTO, Object>> functionMap = new HashMap<>();
functionMap.put("v", TradeChartDTO::getVolume);
functionMap.put("l", TradeChartDTO::getLow);
functionMap.put("h", TradeChartDTO::getHigh);
functionMap.put("c", chart -> new BigDecimal(chart.getClose()));
functionMap.put("o", chart -> new BigDecimal(chart.getOpen()));
functionMap.put("t", chart -> new BigDecimal(chart.getTimestamp()));

Map<String, Object> mainData = functionMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Entry::getKey,
    e -> tradeChartDTO.stream().map(e.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList())
));
```

The real benefit is questionable, however, you save half of the lines. It's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a `SummarDetails` class with 5 constructors, and getters for low, close, open...

Create instances of `SummaryDeails` by passing all the 5 values during one pass as per below

`List<SummaryDetails> listOfSummary = tradeChartDTO.stream().map(chart -> new SummaryDetails(chart.getLow(), ... ).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Then put it in Map.